# How to make keyPress activate a handleClick in Typescript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, components

Making a simple registraction form in React/TS, and
I'm trying to make the Enter key perform the role of clicking Next. It should do everything that the next button does, which is defined in handleClick.

```
    function handleKeyPress(e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>) {
        if (e.code === "Enter") {
            handleClick( // some argument here // );
        }
    }

    function handleClick(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {
        if (!first || !last) {
            return setError(true);
        }
        step(e, `${e.currentTarget.name}`);
        updateName(e, first, last);
    }
```

I cannot work out which argument to pass to handleClick, in order to satisfy Typescript. It requires 1 argument.

I have tried passing e: React.MouseEvent, and variations of arbitrary arguments. What am I missing here?

Comment: You can use an intermediate function that calls `step` and `updateName`, then call that from both `handleClick` and `handleKeyPress`, passing no longer an event but just the elements/strings/data you actually need.

Comment: The issue there, is that step and updateName come from the parent component, and also require the event as an argument. Is there anything wrong with making the event an optional parameter in this case?